# comparing sys date with timestamp on filename in talend open studio

Tags: business-intelligence, talend

I have a folder containing excels in this format "Sales_09-03-17.xls". I will have to extract the date from the filename and check if the date matches with the sysdate. I'm new to talend open studio, can anyone pls guide me throguh.

Comment: What did you already try ? What errors did you get ?

Comment: Can you give us your feedback about the solution I've proposed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired files using tFileList.
For your use case, put the following in the "Filemask" field:
`"Sales_" + TalendDate.formatDate("dd-MM-yy",TalendDate.getCurrentDate()) + ".xls"`

Hope this helps.
TRF

Comment: Well, in my answer I've supposed you need  to compare date from filename with system date just to process files of the current day and not others. tFileList is the way to select a files subset based on criteria. If this is not what you need, just tell us for a better answer.